# Setting password for Word doc from Powershell

Tags: vba, powershell, ms-word, password-protection

I'd like to make a Microsoft Word document be set with a password for opening the document. When I try to run the following code in Powershell, the script will hang once I enter the desired password.

This script will be run in Kaseya to help automate protecting Word documents. I've tried both modifying the `Document.Password` property and using the `Document.Protect` method and they both will hang the script.

```bsh
$path = Read-Host("Specify path to word document")

Write-Host "Creating Word application object..."
$wordAppObj = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

Write-Host "Creating Word document object..."
$wordDocObj = $wordAppObj.Documents.Open($path)

# Write-Host "Activating Word document object..."
# $wordDocObj.Activate

Write-Host "Setting password..."
$securePass = Read-Host("Set password as") -AsSecureString
$password = ConvertFrom-SecureString $securePass
# $wordDocObj.Protect(3, $true, $password)
$wordDocObj.Password = $password

Write-Host "Saving Word document object..."
$wordDocObj.Save

Write-Host "Closing the Word document..."
$wordDocObj.Close

Write-Host "Closing Word..."
$wordAppObj.Application.Quit()
```

I expect the script to run through and protect the file, but the script will hang and an instance of Microsoft Word will be running in the background taking up about 6-9% of the CPU. Nothing will happen to the file or in the script. There are no error messages that pop up.

UPDATE: As suggested, I added `$wordAppObj.Visible = $true` to the script to see if there were any pop-ups that happened during the execution of the script. Unfortunately, I didn't see any. I believe the script may be hanging when it prompts the user to re-enter the password. This happens when I use Word to encrypt a document with a password. Is there any way to fill this field in from Powershell?

Comment: Might be worth setting `$wordAppObject.Visible = $true` before anything else, it might be hanging because of an error dialog or prompt

Comment: When something like this happens often the Office application is showing a message and awaiting user input. That's why Word might appear to "hang". Are you able to look at the Word user interface to check that? (Note: you do not want this `$wordDocObj.Protect(3, $true, $password)` in order to password protect the document against *opening*. This is only a protection against some kinds of *editing*).

Comment: I will try both of these suggestions. I'll add an edit to the post with an update. Thank you!

Comment: I used your code as a example and the script worked with I didn't use the Read-Host to set the password, when I statically set the password in the code it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed a program in C# with the Microsoft Interop reference for Word. This program worked for me. At this point, I believe that this kind of thing cannot be done from Powershell and I would advise that anyone trying to do this seek another way to get this done. I think Powershell simply doesn't support modifying the password field of a document.